# An interviewer has asked for a copy of an unpublished manuscript I'm writing, is it safe to do this?

Tags: publications, interview

The paper is one I'm working on as part of my current role for which I'm not the PI. Is it safe/sensible to share this with my interviewer? I don't have any published articles at present, so I assume they are just interested in seeing writing samples and such. Should I offer them a copy of my PhD thesis instead?

The interview was for a job in academia I am applying for.

Comment: What do you mean by "interviewer"? Are you trying to find a new position? In academia, or industry? Are you being interviewed for a newspaper?

Comment: It's an interview for a new position within academia. I'll amend this in the question.

Comment: Are you the lead researcher on the paper or is it just something you are contributing to?

Comment: I'll be the lead author on the paper yes, but I'm just a research assistant on the grant.

Comment: Do you have explicit permission from each of your coauthors to share the manuscript?  If not, you can't ethically share the manuscript, even if you are the lead author/PI.  (Just like submitting for publication.)

Comment: "Do you have explicit permission from each of your coauthors to share the manuscript? If not, you can't ethically share the manuscript"  I think that's an extreme view.  Showing somebody a paper in progress is not an important decision.  (I have many coauthors on each paper and I work in a field where there is no confidential information from human subjects.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no concrete, objective answer to this. My opinion is that it's fairly safe to give unpublished manuscripts to an academic interviewer. You definitely need specific permission from all the co-authors on the manuscript, though. If the interviewer is directly in the same field as you, and might be working on the same topic, you might be more hesitant, but it's not a definite "no".  Hopefully, if you're interviewing and considering working with this person, you've already decided that they are not a horrible human being, so you've already done a little of the due diligence.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is odd for an interviewer to ask for an unpublished paper. It is common for researchers to share partial results though...If your paper is already under review and you, and your co authors believe it is safe to share it, I do not see any problem. Just be aware that there are many awful people in academia, and it is not uncommon for ideas to be stolen.

Comment: Do you know of ideas being stolen? My understanding is that it is not actually as common as people tend to think.

Comment: Maybe it was just unlucky... or maybe the other group was actually working on a similar project,...,but happened to a friend of mine. He presented his work to another researcher and months latter the other researcher published something similar, right before him.

Comment: @JessicaB It is not often that ideas get stolen, but it happens, and if it does, it can get *very* ugly. Being cautious is thus like an insurance. It is not often that a house burns down/car gets stolen/etc, but you'd rather it not happen or, if it does, be protected.

Comment: @Tuco In maths at least it is very common for someone else to be working on the same thing at the same time. I know of a number of instances, one myself.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs So you don't agree with 'it is not uncommon...'?

Comment: @JessicaB You have to weigh the probability against the cost, that's what I am trying to say. I am aware of at least 2 clear cases where ideas were either stolen or an attempt made to do so, and a number of suspected cases (not mine). It's not a lot overall, on the whole, but it's infuriating nonetheless to whoever it happens.